# Frozen Powershell form when executing SSH commands

Tags: ssh, powershell, forms

Have a simple script that runs via Powershell form

By request, it getting information form Linux servers, using `plink` command, and then prints it as an output in the form.
The problem that the form is freezing while getting information.

I have tried to use `get-job`, same result

My original command:

```
plink -batch -ssh $User@$srv -pw $pass -m $executeCommandFile | fl | out-string
```

Added `get-job` logic:

```
$myjob = start-job -scriptblock {plink -batch -ssh $User@$srv -pw $pass -m $executeCommandFile | fl | out-string}
While ( ($myjob | Select-Object -ExpandProperty State) -eq "Running") {
                    sleep 1
                }
$results = receive-job -job $myjob
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the steps. Try sending the plink data request to a temp file, have a monitor on the temp location and when the data write completes, use your form code to read the temp file data back to your form vs the background job approach.

Comment: Tried it already. plink data request is part of the form code, so it still waits until it write to the file. Don't have the knowledge to separate it from the form code, background job and temp file is what I found in the internet. But it is not good for this case

Comment: Q: What is in that batch file? Q: Are you getting any results to the file/UI at all? Also, I meant to add in my first response you are using a variable, in a local scope, vs remote scope. See this and specifically 'Example 5: Using a Local Variable in a Remote Command'

Comment: 1. if ! [[ "$(dpkg -l)" =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$package"(\$|[[:space:]]) ]]; then echo 1; fi; \\ checks if a certain linux package is installed, using `dpkg` command

Comment: 2. The output is NULL or 1, getting it into a variable and then doing relevant calculations

Comment: 3. You mean invoke-command?